# How do I execute a piece of code no more than every X minutes?

Tags: node.js

Say I have a link aggregation app where users vote on links. I sort the links using hotness scores generated by an algorithm that runs whenever a link is voted on. However running it on every vote seems excessive. How do I limit it so that it runs no more than, say, every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

a) use cron job

b) keep track of the timestamp when the procedure was last run, and when the current timestamp - the timestamp you have stored > 5 minutes then run the procedure and update the timestamp.

Comment: Why to use a cron? let the cron for other languages like PHP and so on. node.js runs your process without interruption so you can use setTimeout.

Comment: @coma You'd probably want to use `setInterval` rather than `setTimeout` if you want the code to execute more than once...

Comment: no, please watch http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=i_qE1iAmjFg#t=462s

Comment: Unfortunately I know very little about node.js. But if its running one instance per thread (or process) like in a web server instance setTimeout will not work because you will just be stacking multiple setTimeouts on top of each other just delaying execution. Also setTimeout is not fine grained like threading inside a kernel. Although I'm not sure that is relevant. If you don't want to deal with cron than use the b method I said above.

Comment: setTimeout (and all other asynchronous callers like nextTick) respects the Javascript's scheduler and has no problem of handling multiple postponed calls as they don't block, and they are rescheduled as they respect all other scheduled callbacks. It'll have the same result as having a great amount of event listeners, and events calling them.

Answer (score 1):

```
var yourVoteStuff = function() { 

    ...

    setTimeout(yourVoteStuff, 5 * 60 * 1000);
};

yourVoteStuff();
```

Before asking why not to use setTimeinterval, well, read the comment below.

Why "why setTimeinterval" and no "why cron job?"?, am I that wrong?

Comment: Why not use `setinterval`?

Comment: If inside yourVoteStuff, something longs more than 5 minutes you will be in troubles since setTimeinterval will call it again, please watch http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=i_qE1iAmjFg#t=462s , so, this way you ensure that this will run 5 min after the last completed stuff.

Answer (score 1):

- First you build a receiver that receives all your links submissions.
- Secondly, the receiver push()es each link (that has been received) to
  a queue (I strongly recommend [redis](http://redis.io/))
- Moreover you have an aggregator which loops with a time interval of your desire. Within this loop each queued link should be poll()ed and continue to your business logic.

I have use this solution to a production level and I can tell you that scales well as it also performs.

Example of use;

```
var MIN = 5; // don't run aggregation for short queue, saves resources
var THROTTLE = 10; // aggregation/sec
var queue = [];
var bucket = [];
var interval = 1000; // 1sec

flow.on("submission", function(link) {
    queue.push(link);
});

___aggregationLoop(interval);
function ___aggregationLoop(interval) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        bucket = [];
        if(queue.length<=MIN) {
            ___aggregationLoop(100); // intensive
            return;
        }
        for(var i=0; i<THROTTLE; ++i) {
            (function(index) {
                bucket.push(this);
            }).call(queue.pop(), i);
        }
        ___aggregationLoop(interval);
    }, interval);
}
```

Cheers!