# setTimeout and kineticjs

Tags: canvas, kineticjs

I want to fire objects with a timeout. The problem is that the below code only fires the first object. Does anybody know how I can fire in diferent times the tweens?

```
function _tween_out(_objeto){
    _objeto.play();
}
function _tween_in(_objeto){
    _objeto.reverse();
}
myVar=[]
bk.on('mouseenter', function(evt) { 

for (var j=0;j<iconos_bases.length;j++){
        var mandar=iconos_bases[j].group.tween
        myVar[j]=setTimeout(function(){_tween_out(mandar)},getRandomInt(1,100));
    }
    stage.draw();

});
```

I change the code.

```
 function _tween_out(_objeto){
    _objeto.play();
}
function _tween_in(_objeto){
    _objeto.reverse();
}
myVar=[]
bk.on('mouseenter', function(evt) { 

for (var j=0;j<iconos_bases.length;j++){
        var mandar=iconos_bases[j].group.tween
        var num=getRandomInt(1,600000);
        console.log(num);
        setTimeout(_tween_out(mandar),num);
    }

    stage.draw();

});
```

but all the timeout in the same time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16532177/stopping-dynamically-generated-setinterval/16532252#16532252

Answer (score 1):

One thing: How much time delay are you calculating here?

```
// 600000 seems like a large number ??

var num=getRandomInt(1,600000);
```

Anyway...

**A Demo:**  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/CTRuq/

In setTimeout you can't send arguments with your _tween_out function.

```
// This Won't Work !

setTimeout(_tween_out(mandar),num);
```

If you want to send an argument you must instead give setTimeout an anonymous function:

```
setTimeout( function(){ _tween_out(mandar); }, num );
```

Comment: Thank you, also I detect in my code that the array go to memory after the declaration, for this give me empty.. ;) more hours after.  For me "Timeout" it is too late, I find this librarys TweenLite that works with Kineticjs and go very well. Put a exmaple.   myVar[j]=TweenLite.to(iconos_bases[j].group,1, {kinetic:{x : 900} ,ease:Strong.easeOut,delay:Math.random() * 0.4,});  Thank you and sorry my bad english.

Comment: Yep, Greensock (and tweenLite) is an excellent library for transformations, tweens and animations.